# How do I remove top and bottom padding of text

Tags: html, css

```css
.close {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

So basically there is a padding on the top and bottom I want to remove. I tried with line heights but it didn't work. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:inline-block` first then you can play with `line-height`

```css
.close {
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<span class="close">&times;</span>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But if I select the text it will still select the padding. Is there a way to remove that too?

Answer (score 0):

This works without extra padding when selected:

```css
.close {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.close {
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.5;
}

.close::selection{ 
  background: none;
  color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<span class="close">&times;</span>
```

What you are looking for is `::selection` property of CSS. You can write custom CSS within this and your selected element will behave the same.